# Junk characters shows up while opening a txt file

Tags: perl, character-encoding

When I open a file which is .txt format it shows ^@(special characters) along with the actual data. But while printing the lines through Perl script it doesn't shows up. If the same is written to the output file it again shows up the special characters. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: "when I open a file" - do you mean you open the file with an editor, e.g. vim or Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

`^@` represents a NUL byte (also known as `\0`). If you have a lot of those in what's supposed to be a text file, that likely means the file is in UTF-16 but you're treating it as ASCII (or Latin-1 or UTF-8).